# How to get bottom border to only display under padded text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the bottom border to only display under the padded text.

[image]

```html
<h1 style="font-size: 32px; color: #060428; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 4px solid #4ac2c5; display: inline; margin: 50px 0px 0px; padding-left: 30px;"><span style="font-family: verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Headline</span></h1>
```

Comment: is the use of padding needed or you can rely on margin? (to know If I add answer with padding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `padding-left: 30px;`

```html
<h1 style="font-size: 32px; color: #060428; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 4px solid #4ac2c5; display: inline; margin: 50px 0px 0px; "><span style="font-family: verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Headline</span></h1>
```

Or replace with margin to still 'push' the text to the right;

```html
<h1 style="font-size: 32px; color: #060428; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 4px solid #4ac2c5; display: inline; margin: 50px 0px 0px 30px;"><span style="font-family: verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Headline</span></h1>
```

Comment: I didn't realise I was missing the 4th variable for margin and should have been using that rather then using the padding.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `border-bottom` style to `span` instead.

Inline styles generally aren't good practice so I've included the CSS separately.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #060428;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

span {
  font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #4ac2c5;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Headline</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks @Codese.

Unfortunately I'm using a marketing automation platform to design an email template and it doesn't allow for CSS in the template editor.